How to modify PrimeNg pTooltip directive to stop listening on Escape button
I have a list of 1000 rows and each of them has pTooltip on it.
<div *ngFor="let l of longList">
     <div [pTooltip]="'Hi'">Text</div>
</div>

When I press Escape, the website freezes for about 7s, because of many digest cycles.

I know it is possible to listen on body tag and stopPropagation of Escape event, but then I have to manually handle this event (e.g. to close some dialog)
Disabling hideOnEscape input doesn't solve the problem.

Is it possible to write custom directive that will modify behaviour of pTooltip directive or change its behaviour using ViewChild ? Other ideas are welcome :) .

On the component level, you can use the below code, to watch for escape key press and stop the event propogation. We use zone.runOutsideAngular to make sure this listener runs outside angular, so that it can prevent the event from happening and the application won't hang.
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    window.document.addEventListener("keydown", (e: KeyboardEvent) => { 
        if((e.which || e.keyCode) === 27) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});


You need to implement virtual scrolling, it's designed to solve this particular problem of too many html elements within a web page affecting performance.
Instead of hacking the tooltip, modify the table to have virtual scrolling, the performance will automatically improve.
You can use @angular/cdk's virtual scroll.
Virtual Scroll Examples - Angular CDK

Adding virtual scrolling would be greater effort than catching "escape event" on body tag and stopPropagation on it and do other things when necessary. Especially since my list elements are not equal height and their height can be changed by user. I'm not sure if it would be possible to write such "Scrolling strategy" to handle that case.

@Borneo777 updated my answer, try this code, in the root component or the component where the looping happens, it should solve your problem if virtual scroll is not possible.

I suppose you haven't read my question and my comment cerefully. I wrote "1. I know it is possible to listen on body tag and stopPropagation of Escape event, but then I have to manually handle this event (e.g. to close some dialog)". As you see I know your solution, but I'm looking for better one.

@Borneo777 I also said you can attach it to the component you have the for loop on to stop this problem
